# Passing precision to python's .format method

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a variable that I need to write with different precisions depending on the case, sometimes I'll need two decimal places and other times more.

Recently I've been trying to use the [string.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method instead of the `%` operator but I can't figure out how to do this apparently simple thing.

Here's a MWE:

```
# Some variable.
a=5.2365548
# Define two precisions.
x, y = 2, 5
# Print 'a' with different precisions.
print 'The variable equals: {:.xf}'.format(a)
print 'The variable equals: {:.yf}'.format(a)
```

which would ideally return in each case:

```
The variable equals: 5.24
The variable equals: 5.23655
```

Of course using `:.xf` doesn't work but I believe it shows what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> print '{:.{prec}f}'.format(12.345, prec=2)
12.35
>>> print '{:.{prec}f}'.format(12.345, prec=1)
12.3
```